# How to move variables containing date in inner subquery to outer subquery in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The following query works well, displaying 2018th year all mondays in each month.

```
select dt3 from unnest(generate_date_array(date_trunc('2018-1-1',week(monday)),'2019-1-1',interval 1 week))dt3
```

But in the above query I want to replace **date_trunc('2018-1-1',week(monday))** with **start_date** and **'2019-1-1',interval 1 week** with **end_date**. So I wrote the following query, but it didn't worked. Any suggestion.

```
select dt2 from unnest(generate_date_array(start_date,end_date))dt2 from(select date_add(start_date,interval 371 day)end_date,start_date from (select date_trunc('2018-1-1',week(monday))start_date))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT 1 seq, DATE_TRUNC('2018-1-1',week(monday)) start_date, DATE '2019-1-1' end_date 
)
SELECT dt2 
FROM dates, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) dt2
```

In case if you want to only start_date (as in second query in your question):

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT 1 seq, DATE_TRUNC('2018-1-1',week(monday)) start_date 
)
SELECT dt2 
FROM dates, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL 371 DAY), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) dt2
```